# Require output always of format 2 digit to right and 7 digit to left of decimal

Tags: java, android, decimal

I want output string of double value of latitude and longitude with 1,2 or 3 digits before decimal and 7 digits after decimal point .How to do this using DecimalFormat() in java?

```
    12.456789   should give 12.4567890
    12.45678912 should give 12.4567891
```

thanks in advance

Comment: so 1.2345 should be 01.2345000 ? and -160.1234567 is ok?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes u r ryt , i just want exactly 7 digits after decimal

Comment: But you need exactly two digits before the decimal place or can it be 1,2 or 3?

Comment: @PeterLawrey it should be 1,2 or 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
String s = new DecimalFormat("00.0000000").format(12.456789);
```

this version is with a fixed integer length, or

```
  String s = new DecimalFormat("0.0000000").format(12.456789);
```

with a floating length

Comment: will this always return 7 digits after decimal?

Answer (score 1):

`String formatted = new DecimalFormat("##.######").format(input)`;

Answer (score 1):

> I just want exactly 7 digits after decimal

this will always give you 7 deciaml places, rounding as required.

```
String s = String.format("%.7f", lat);
```

to do both at once

```
String s = String.format("lat %.7f, long %.7f", lat, long);
```